# How assert data property for classes in Protege?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, protege4

I want to model `Person` class which takes data property `givenName` of type `xsd:string`. How to specify length restriction of this property (say `maxLength=50`) that is applicable only for `Person` class? For example, I want to allow other classes to use the same property and choose different value for restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, OWL is not a constraint language. It is intended rather to define classes based on restrictions, than to set up restrictions for classes.

However, one can define anonymous “restriction-based” class and declare another class to be a subclass of this anonymous class.

In the Manchester syntax, you can write something like this:

```
Class: Person
    SubClassOf: givenName only xsd:string[maxLength 5]
```

In the Functional syntax:

```
SubClassOf(
    :Person
    DataAllValuesFrom(
        :givenName
        DatatypeRestriction(
            xsd:string
            xsd:maxLength "5"^^xsd:string
        )
    )
)
```

In the Turtle syntax:

```
:Person rdfs:subClassOf
    [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty :givenName ;
      owl:allValuesFrom
      [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
        owl:onDatatype xsd:string ;
        owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:maxLength "5"^^xsd:string ] )
      ]
    ] .
```

The image below is the "[Class description](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/class-description/)" view in Protégé:

[image: Class description view]

Now suppose you declare that

```
Individual: He
    Types: Person
    Facts: givenName  "Alexander"^^xsd:string
```

Then reasoner (e.g. HermiT) have to say that your ontology is inconsistent:

[image: Inconsistent ontology explanation]

Comment: Great. This is very helpful. Thanks